# Start my Android service with accepted user permissions

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions

I have a little specific issue and I want some tips for that. I need to start just one time an Android service, and I can use these 2 options:

1. Start the service from the `onCreate()` method of the `MainActivity`. The problem with this way is when the device is rotated with my app running, the `onCreate()` method is called again, because the `MainActivity` is restarted and I don't want that my service restarted because of this.
2. Start it from the Android `Application` **class**. The problem is that before start the service, I need to check if some permissions was accepted by the user. So the first time that my application is started in the `Application` **class** the permissions are not accepted yet.

Reading this article [Handle configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) I can see that is possible avoid the restart of my `MainActivity` but I don't know if this is a good practice. So maybe exist some way to request user permissions from the `Application`

Comment: Do you need your Activity recreated on rotate? If not, adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your Activity in the manifest is the simplest solution.

Comment: It is the simplest, but do you think that is the recommended? Because what can be the implications of handle the config changes manually?

Comment: Resources will not be reloaded if you have *_land resources, for ex. Fragments can also benefit from not ignoring the config change. It is a case by case basis, and you need to understand the implications of a config change on the elements in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

1. `onCreate` with be called once during Service lifecycle, but `onStartCommand` will be called every time you call `startService`
2. You can't request user permission outside Activity context. So, you can run service but you are unable to do something that requires permission. You may register BroadcastReceiver inside your service for catching some "permission granted" intents. But this intent should be created and sended to service via broadcast in Activity context at the moment when user grants permission. Or you may use service commands instead

Answer (score 0):

To prevent restarting your service just check in your MainActivity `onCreate` method is your service running

**Function for checking service running:**

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And after that you just need to call it in your `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if(!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)) {
   //start your service
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the reason why you would like to start the service only once but I am gonna try to suggest an alternative to achieve this.

1. Since you would like to ask for a user's permissions, the service cannot be started in the application class. So the only place you can start it is in the activity class. 
   The key to solve this will be the `onCreate` and `onStartCommand` methods.
   If you define the service in the manifest file and then call  `Context.startService(context)` multiple times, `onCreate` will be called only once as long as the system has not killed the service yet.
   `onStartCommand` will be called every time you call `Context.startService(context)`.

Hence in this approach, write the block of code that you need to be executed once in the `onCreate` method. For all updates, execute them in the  `onStartCommand` method.

2. Another option would be to dig deeper into android architecture components (LiveData, LifeCycle and observers)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to deal with android's infamous rotation is to use `ViewModel`. As `ViewModel` survives device's rotation you can store a `liveData` of `boolean` initially set to `true` and observe it in `onCreate()`. Start the service only if the observed value is `true` and set it to `false` once you have started the service. Please see the following example,

In **ViewModel**

```
val startService = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(true)
```

In **Activity**'s `onCreate()`

```
viewModel.startService.observe(this, Observer {
        if (it) {
            startService()
            viewModel.startService.value = false
        }
})
```